# Specs2's acceptance specification can't work with 'Scope'

Tags: scala, specs2

I have some specs2 tests with `Scope`:

```
"hello" should {
   "return world" in new Subject {
       hello.get === "world"
   }
}
trait Subject extends org.specs2.specification.Scope {
   val hello = new Hello
}
```

Now I want to convert it into acceptance style:

```
def is = s2"""
   hello.get should return 'world' $e1
"""
def e1 = new Subject {
    hello.get === "world"
}
trait Subject extends org.specs2.specification.Scope {
   val hello = new Hello
}
```

It seems working and the test is passed, but soon I found it's never failed no matter how I modify it:

```
hello.get === "invalid-world" // still passing
```

How to use `Scope` correctly in acceptance style?

Answer (score 1):

Just found an issue for this problem: https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/issues/180

The answer quoted from there:

> This is to be expected. Scopes are traits which are only intended to be used with mutable 
>   specifications. You have 2 ways around this:
>
> use a case class or case object
>
> ```
> s2"""
>  will fail      ${t.fail}
> """
> case object t {
>   val foo = false
>   def fail = foo must beTrue
> }
> ```
>
> mix-in the `ThrownExpectations` trait to the `Specification` so that failed expectations will "bubble-up" 
>   outside of the Scope trait